Recovering as much history as possible from corrupt git repository
I used photorec to recover zlib files from a disk image taken just after a git repository was deleted (instructions here). It recovered many (most?) but not all of the contents of the .git/objects folder. This means I can checkout main and have all but 1 file (luckily trivial) present, so thankfully the up to date source code still exists, and git log goes back about ~6 months but eventually it fails to find a parent commit. git gc and git repack similarly fail due to missing parent commits.
git fsck --full reports many broken links from trees to blobs, as well as dangling blobs and commits. Some of these are due to using photorec -- I simply recovered everything it could find in the disk image in zlib format and put it in .git/objects with the appropriate sha1 subfolder and name. This means there are objects from other git repos in there! I thought git gc would take care of those for me, but as I said it fails to run.
Since I have a full copy of the up to date source, I could just start a new repo, but then I would lose ALL the history. It would be nice if there were a way to prune the repository to only include what is reachable from the current branch, going back to the last commit that successfully appears in git log, and nuke everything else. Is there a way to do that or similar? Ideally, I would keep as much history as possible but have a clean git fsck.
